# XSL Stylesheet for dynamic XML Data

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to create 1 XSL style sheet that can create HTML Table code with data specific headers and column counts. Here are two example sets of data I want processed by 1 style sheet

```
<root> 
      <row> 
        <postId>1</postId> 
        <id>1</id> 
        <name>name 1</name> 
        <email>email_1@gardner.biz</email> 
        <body>body 1</body> 
      </row> 
      <row> 
        <postId>1</postId> 
        <id>2</id> 
        <name>name 2</name> 
        <email>email_2@gardner.biz</email> 
        <body>body 2</body> 
      </row> 
</root>

<root> 
      <row> 
        <id>1</id> 
        <desc>desc 1</desc> 
        <Note>Note 1</Note> 
      </row> 
      <row> 
        <id>2</id> 
        <desc>desc 2</desc> 
        <Note>Note 2</Note> 
      </row> 
      <row> 
        <id>3</id> 
        <desc>desc 3</desc> 
        <Note>Note 3</Note>
      </row> 
</root>
```

Then I'd like the sheet to produce outputs like:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>postId</th><th>id</th><th>name</th><th>email</th><th>body</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td><td>1</td><td>mane 1</td><td>email_1@gardner.biz</td><td>body 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>mane 2</td><td>email_2@gardner.biz</td><td>body 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

<table>
  <thead>
    <th>id</th><th>desc</th><th>Note</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td><td>desc 1</td><td>Note 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td><td>desc 2</td><td>Note 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td><td>desc 3</td><td>Note 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I've figured out the table header (see below) but I can't seem to get the body to work. I can't figure out how to show a value of an element I don't know the name of or even if one exists.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="root">
  <html>
    <body>
      <h2>My Table Data</h2>
        <table border="1">
          <thead>
            <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
              <xsl:for-each select="row[1]/*">
                <th><xsl:value-of select ="name(.)"/></th>        
              </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody> 
            ?????
          </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `row` elements always has the same number of elements, and in the same order, you wouldn't have to worry about the names, and your ????? could simply be replaced by this....

```
<xsl:for-each select="row">
   <tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="*">
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
         </td>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

On the other hand, if the `row` elements could have elements in different order, or even missing, then (assuming the first row was always complete), you could define a variable holding the "header" row cells

```
 <xsl:variable name="headers" select="row[1]/*"/>
```

Then your ???? becomes this...

```
<xsl:for-each select="row">
    <xsl:variable name="currentRow" select="."/>
    <tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="$headers">
        <xsl:variable name="currentHeaderName" select="name()" />
           <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="$currentRow/*[name() = $currentHeaderName]"/>
           </td>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="root">
      <html>
        <body>
            <h2>My Table Data</h2>
            <xsl:variable name="headers" select="row[1]/*"/>
            <table border="1">
              <thead>
                  <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                     <xsl:for-each select="$headers">
                        <th>
                           <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
                        </th>        
                     </xsl:for-each>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody> 
                  <xsl:for-each select="row">
                    <xsl:variable name="currentRow" select="."/>
                    <tr>
                        <xsl:for-each select="$headers">
                        <xsl:variable name="currentHeaderName" select="name()" />
                           <td>
                              <xsl:value-of select="$currentRow/*[name() = $currentHeaderName]"/>
                           </td>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </tr>
                  </xsl:for-each>
              </tbody>
             </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```